# why can i make instance more than my cpu count in pm2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, cpu, pm2

I installed pm2 in my local pc
Then, i made ecosystem.config.cjs file.

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'app',
            script: './app.js',
            instance_var: 'INSTANCE_ID',
            instances: 0,
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
        },
    ],
};
```

According to what I understand, instances feature value is 0 means make cluster by max my pc cpu count.
My Pc cpu count is 8.
But, when i ran a below command

```
pm2 scale app 10
```

10 cluster were made.

How can this possible ..??

How are more than 8 clusters created?

I try to solve this problem but i can't found definitely solution like this problem

Comment: Some context would be nice. Tell us what you did so far to try to solve your question.

Comment: I don't know pm2 specifically, but presumably it just means it will start 10 threads or processes, so the host OS will have to context-switch between them if they're all busy at once.  The number of logical cores on your actual machine is a good choice for number of simultaneous CPU-intensive tasks to have running, for performance reasons.

Comment: There are more than 8 instances in the cluster because you told it to create 10. That's all. When you give a command directly to pm2 it overrides whatever you configured in the ecosystem file. Note that in the example above you only have 1 cluster, not 10 and it should not be 8. It should be 1 cluster. The cluster should have 10 instances/processes because you told it to start 10 instances. You can have another node.js project that run another cluster in your machines with 5 instances or 100 instances etc. Then you'd have 2 clusters.